# Why does my GLKView scale down during rotation?

Tags: iphone, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I have a an object in my GLKView that I rotate during the `touchesMoved` method. However, upon rotation, the matrix scales as well which is kind of weird. Can somebody detect the problem ?

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {


    self.opaque = NO;
    self.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


}



-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{



    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint lastLoc = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(lastLoc.x - location.x, lastLoc.y - location.y);

    float rotX = -1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(diff.y / 2.0);

    GLKVector3 xAxis = GLKVector3Make(1, 0, 0);
    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(rotMatrix, rotX, xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z);

    float aspect = fabsf(self.bounds.size.width / self.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 4.0f, 10.0f);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix, rotMatrix);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

    [self display];

}
```

Comment: comment out the line that goes `modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix, rotMatrix);` and run it again and see if it still squishes even without the rotation. I dont see anything wrong with this code as it stands, could be something else. I would blame something on not being normalized (but there doesnt seem to be anything like that in your code), some float rounding imprecision can lead to stuff like that sometimes. can also try setting rotMatrix to the identity before calculating the rotation.

Comment: Hi Fonix, unfortunately both of your suggestions did not work. I have absolutely no idea what happens that it scales down. It is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the value of GLKMathDegreesToRadians to lesser values scales you cube size.

Give the values less than 65.0f to GLKMathDegreesToRadians,as an example

```
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(35.0f), aspect, 4.0f, 10.0f);
```